# group and sum in linq to sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I wanted to sum the DayDifference based on studentId

```
 List<Timeliness> studentData = (from redt in RoundEndDateTable.AsEnumerable()
                                                join st in Activity on redt.Field<string>("strActivityName") equals st.ActivityName
                                                orderby (DateTime.Parse(redt.ItemArray[1].ToString()) - DateTime.Parse(st.RewardType.ToString())) descending
                                                select new Timeliness
                                                {

                                                    DayDifference = int.Parse((DateTime.Parse(redt.ItemArray[1].ToString()) - DateTime.Parse(st.RewardType)).ToString().Split('.')[0]),
                                                    StudentId = st.AssociateId.ToString()
                                                }).ToList();
```

I tried the below code

```
var groupedCustomerList = studentData
    .GroupBy(u => u.StudentId)
    .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Not sure where to add the sum in the above codes

In the first query i am getting student id repeated

ex:

```
[0]  - studentid:123 DayDifference:16
[1]  - studentid:123 DayDifference:8
[2]  - studentid:121 DayDifference:16
```

I need

```
[0]  - studentid:123 DayDifference:24
[2]  - studentid:121 DayDifference:16
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should create a collection of anonymous types, containing each "Key" (StudentId), and the sum of the "DayDifference" values for each StudentId:

```
var result =
    studentData.GroupBy(u => u.StudentId)
               .Select(grp => new { Id = grp.Key, TotalDiff = grp.Sum(x => x.DayDifference) })
               .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks ! :)
Would appreciate if you could share your fav book/blog post for learning linq

Comment: @vignesh I've found this page from MSDN to be a good resource: [101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)